# Change default locale in Android app using eclipse

Tags: android, localization

Is there a way to set the locale for an Android app at build/compile time?

The usecase is that the localization is really selected at build time, and can't be changed by the user. So each localization of the app, is really a new app.

The app is build using Eclipse, so I am not using gradle.

Comment: Write different versions of your app. Each one localizes to a specific locale in `onCreate()`. It might be as simple as changing a value in an xml or a txt file.

Comment: That's what I do now, but it seems wasteful.

Comment: Does it work? Don't ask yourself for more. Different methods may be **more wasteful**.

Comment: It works, but it causes the build to be bigger then needed because it include resources for languages which are newer used.

Comment: I guess it's a **little** price to pay... How bigger is the app? Let's say each resource file is **10 KB**. Let's say you have arrays and strings: **20 KB** per language. Let's say you support 10 languages (really?). Total: **200 KB**. They will be zipped in the apk. Text file compression is about **10:1**. Total in the apk: **20 KB**. I guess it's **acceptable**.